# Use same install disk on multiple PCs

Tags: 14.04, system-installation

I have a Ubuntu 14.04 disk. I have sucsesfully installed it on my computer, but now I've got couple more of old computers and I was wondering if I could use same installation disk on 7 more PC's.

Thank you for answers

Comment: The beauty of Ubuntu. Of course you can. The more the merrier. If you plan to get them ready for friends consider an OEM install by pressing spacebar or shift right away: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Ubuntu_OEM_Installer_Overview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes of course you can, so long as they support booting from the installation media you have.